# Event listener for multiple draggable rectangles using imrect in matlab

Tags: matlab, event-listener

I have following code snippet in which I am drawing multiple draggable rectangles on the image.

```
function computeButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to computeButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
PImage=handles.ProcessedImage;
Image=handles.Image;
imshow(Image);
hold on;
bw=bwconncomp(PImage,4);
regions=regionprops(bw,'BoundingBox','PixelIdxList');
for i=1:length(regions)
    box=regions(i).BoundingBox;
    h=imrect(gca,box);
    %rectangle('Position',box,'EdgeColor','black','LineWidth',2);
end
```

I want to make an event listener that would record the properties(height,width) of all the rectangles and even the changes on  each of the draggable rectangles on the Image.

Comment: This sounds like the `addNewPositionCallback` method for `imrect` objects, described in the [main documentation for `imrect`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html).

Comment: I have used that inside the loop and it works well but the issue is that since there are bunch of rectangles I want to detect changes in all of those rectangles and save them to some text file?

Comment: Keep hold of the handles of all your `imrect`s then (e.g. `h(i)=imrect(gca,box);`) and pass all the handles to the callback, either by defining the callback as a [local function](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) or [anonymous function](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) or using [`guidata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).